# The commutator subgroup of finite metabelian p-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, metabelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite metabelian $p$-group, i.e. the commutator subgroup $G′$ of $G$ is abelian. In some paper of groups theory, I find This statement :

" Since $G/G'$ $\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then $G'$ is cyclic"

I need to know if there is a generalization of that result in groups theory ? i.e if we have that $G/G' \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ a prime, so what informations we can get about $G'$ ??

Comment: What sort of generalization are you looking for? It's not true that $G'$ is cyclic when $p>2$.

Comment: First I need to know the reference for reading the proof of the case of of the statement  above for the case p=2. Also I need to know waht is the structure of G' if G/G' is of type (p,p) ??

Answer (score 1):

In any non-abelian $p$-group, the derived subgroup is of index at least $p^2$.

It is a natural question to ask about structure of groups for which equality holds.

The answer is completely known if $p=2$. What are such $2$-groups? There are at most four  non-abelian $2$-groups which have a cyclic subgroup of index $2$: they are dihedral ($D_{2^n}$), semi-dihedral $SD_{2^n}$, and quaternion ($Q_{2^n}$).

[$M_{2^n}$ was included in previous answer; but thanks to Holt for pointing out error.].

In these groups, derived subgroup is of index $4$.

A result of Tausky shows that these are the only non-abelian $2$-groups with derived subgroup of index $4$. Reference: See Groups of Prime Power Order, Vol. 1, by Y. Berkovich, its first chapter (titled Groups with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$).

For $p>2$: It seems a difficult question (to me at least) to classify $p$-groups with derived subgroups of index $p^2$. The $p$-groups of maximal nilpotency class is a family of examples of these types, whose classification, up to isomorphism is not known except for small orders (say $p^9$ or $p^{10}$ - sorry, I not remembered correctly).

On the other hand, the $2$-groups with $[G:G']=4$ have other characterizations also, and these are quite exceptional groups. You can find them in the chapter 1 of book mentioned above.

Comment: I can't understand what is the relation between the index of $G'$ and its structure (cyclic, bicyclic...) ?? what I need to know is for $p=2$ when $G/G'$ is of type $(2,2)$ how in group theory we get that $G'$ is cyclic ? and if we have the index of $G'$ is $p^2$, then what is the structure of $G'$ for $p>2$.

Comment: The proof goes by induction on $|G|$. Take $N$ to be central subgroup of order $2$ inside $G'$, and look at $\overline{G}=G/N$. By choice of $N$, $[\overline{G}:\overline{G}']=4$, apply induction. Then, trying to determine structure of $G$ (of order $2^{n}$ from structure of central quotient $\overline{G}$ (of order $2^{n-1}$) gives that $G$ is of "same type" among 3.

Comment: The notes by David Craven http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/D.A.Craven/docs/lectures/pgroups.pdf contain proofs of your results in section 4.1 and 4.2.